# How can I solve this problem that shows me the correct output?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

```
import mysql.connector
from tabulate 
import tabulate

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root' , password = '',host = 'localhost', database = 'karmand')

c = cnx.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (
            Name text,
            Weight integer,
            Height integer
            )''')

c.execute('SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY Height DESC ')
print(tabulate(c.fetchall()))
cnx.close()
```

output false;

```
--------  --  ---
Mahdi     90  190
Amin      75  180
Mohammad  75  175
Ahmad     60  175
--------  --  ---
```

output true:

```
--------  --  ---
Mahdi     90  190
Amin      75  180
Ahmad     60  175
Mohammad  75  175
--------  --  ---
```

How can I write a sql command that sorts items based on their height tall and low weight if height are Equal?

Comment: First you'd need to define what you think is *incorrect* about the output.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Order By clause can contain multiple items quite simply. So to order by height and then by weight, do this:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  employee 
ORDER BY 
  Height DESC,
  Weight ASC
```

Live demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7f33f82b79724920be1e1499c4dff9da

Examples of ordering by multiple fields can also be found in many places online, including in the [official MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html).